# ios NSNotification not received in the handler

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I'm using this as the observer:

```
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc addObserver:self
      selector:@selector(newConnection:)
       name:NSFileHandleConnectionAcceptedNotification
         object:nil];
```

This does get called though when it does the app crashes with this message

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayerArray newConnection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x76aed70'
```

This is the newConnection handler which is currently empty:

```
- (void)newConnection:(NSNotification*)notification
{
}
```

It is also declared in the .h file correctly...

this is the code which is calling the notification

```
 socketPort = [[NSSocketPort alloc] initWithTCPPort:portNumber];
    int fd = [socketPort socket];
    fileHandle = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:fd
                                    closeOnDealloc:YES];
...
[fileHandle acceptConnectionInBackgroundAndNotify];
```

edit:
the whole thing above is in a class I've made.
Everything except the newConnection is inside this function:

```
- (id)initWithPortNumber:(int)pn delegate:(id)dl
{
if( self = [super init] ) {
...
}
```

And I called this file in the viewController like this:

```
    SimpleHTTPServer *server= [[SimpleHTTPServer alloc]initWithPortNumber:80 delegate:self];
```

Solution:
The problem was: the view was dealloced because of the arc system 
 the [fileHandle acceptConnectionInBackgroundAndNotify]; Wasn't really a loop that arc detected to it treated the view as idle and automatically dealloced it so I just made a small timer running with a loop every second that leads to an empty method. Which fixed it.

Comment: what is `self` in the first snippet? Also, not related, but avoid `new` in your method names as it may interfere with ARC memory management (not this case, but it could be).

Comment: It makes the current class the observer... In every observer I saw they used self there and it worked perfectly...

Comment: What is keeping `self` alive while it's observing? How many observers are there?

Comment: There is only one observer which is that one and the self is a class that I called from the initial view. I'm editing the code to show what is the thing that calls the notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was: the view was dealloced because of the arc system 
the [fileHandle acceptConnectionInBackgroundAndNotify]; Wasn't really a loop that arc detected to it treated the view as idle and automatically dealloced it so I just made a small timer running with a loop every second that leads to an empty method. Which fixed it.

Comment: A better solution might be to strongly-hold your view, so that ARC doesn't deallocate it.  #justSayin'...  ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you exactly what the error is: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayerArray newConnection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x76aed70'`.

The question you need to ask is "why is the object at `0x76aed70` a `CALayerArray`?"

Start by covering the basics. Set a breakpoint at the `addObserver:…`, make sure `self` is what you think it is. Then set a track that pointer so the debugger will break when it's value is changed. You should be able to track this down quickly.

My guess is your object has been deallocated and you didn't remove the observer.

Comment: I figured out that the "CALayerArray" is actually the "self" I have no idea what it means though I'm updating most of my code in my first post maybe that will give a clue...

Comment: Found the solution. Updating above